# Horizontal rule moving from page to page

Tags: html, css

if you look at my site below, the hr below the title text shifts a bit when i change page. i have made sure every page is charset utf-8 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/notindex.html

this is a simple question and i have researched and tried different things so why the -1 ?
edit:
i also have tried to add a css reset which didn't work.
could it be a conflict between two elements ? if so would adding the IMPORTANT tag fix it ?

Comment: i also have tried to add a css reset which didn't work.

Comment: could it be a conflict between two elements ? if so would adding the IMPORTANT tag fix it ?

Comment: The -1 is likely because you haven't shown what you've tried, or told us what you've researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div#sub is a different height on your homepage than the other pages which is likely forcing the horizontal rule down.

Why not use php to include a common header on every page to enforce consistency:

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
```